# How to use structural search and replace in IntelliJ to convert Java generic declarations to var declarations in local scope only?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, search, replace

I am trying to create an inspection using a structural search and replace template in IntelliJ that will convert generic declarations to var declarations in local scope only. For example, I want to convert code like this:

```java
Map<String, List<String>> myVar = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(10, 2);
```

to:

```java
var myVar = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>(10, 2);
```

I've created a search template that matches the generic declaration, and a replacement template that replaces it with the var declaration. I've also added a script constraint to limit the search and replace to local scope only:

[image]

Search: `$Type$<$GenericArgument$> $Var$ = new $Ctor$<>($Params$);`

replace:`var $Var$ = new $Ctor$<$GenericArgument$>($Params$);`

Full replaceConfiguration:

```xml
<replaceConfiguration name="replace with var" text="$Type$&lt;$GenericArgument$&gt; $Var$ = new $Ctor$&lt;&gt;($Params$);" recursive="false" caseInsensitive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" reformatAccordingToStyle="true" shortenFQN="true" useStaticImport="true" replacement="var $Var$ = new $Ctor$&lt;$GenericArgument$&gt;($Params$);&#10;">
   <constraint name="__context__" script="&quot;__context__.getParent() instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiCodeBlock&quot;" within="" contains="" />
   <constraint name="Type" within="" contains="" />
   <constraint name="GenericArgument" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
   <constraint name="Var" within="" contains="" />
   <constraint name="Params" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
   <constraint name="Ctor" within="" contains="" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

However, when I run the structural search and replace, the resulting code is missing the comma between the generic arguments:

```java
var myVar = new ConcurrentHashMap<String List<String>>(10, 2);
```

How can I modify my search and replace templates to include the comma between the generic arguments?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug, I have filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315080/Comma-between-Java-type-parameter-is-lost-on-replacement)

You can work around the bug by using a replacement variable in the replacement template. The script on the replacement variable can calculate the correct type parameter from the complete type. The script looks like this:

```
def x = Type.getInnermostComponentReferenceElement().getParameterList().getText()
x.substring(1, x.length() - 1)
```

It takes the type and retrieves its type parameter list converts it to text. Then the `<` and `>` are chopped off.

Here is the complete configuration:

```
<replaceConfiguration name="replace with var" text="$Type$&lt;$GenericArgument$&gt; $Var$ = new $Ctor$&lt;&gt;($Params$);" recursive="false" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" search_injected="false" reformatAccordingToStyle="true" shortenFQN="false" replacement="var $Var$ = new $Ctor$&lt;$GenericArgument2$&gt;($Params$);&#10;">
  <constraint name="__context__" script="&quot;__context__.getParent() instanceof com.intellij.psi.PsiCodeBlock&quot;" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Type" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="GenericArgument" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Var" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Params" minCount="0" maxCount="2147483647" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Ctor" within="" contains="" />
  <variableDefinition name="GenericArgument2" script="&quot;def x = Type.getInnermostComponentReferenceElement().getParameterList().getText()&#10;x.substring(1, x.length() - 1)&quot;" />
</replaceConfiguration>
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks!

Note the issue link returns 404

Comment: Sorry, it was a copy-paste mistake. The link is fixed now.